# How to extend validation form request in Laravel 5.2?

Tags: php, laravel

I have this validation request

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use App\Http\Requests\Request;

class CreateUserRequest extends Request
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
          'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
          'password' => 'required|confirmed|min:6',
          'full_name' => 'required',
          'address' => 'required',
          'phone' => 'required|numeric',
          'family_name' => 'required',
          'family_address' => 'required',
          'family_phone' => 'required|numeric',
          'idcard' => 'required|image',
        ];
    }
}
```

I can use it like this in my controller method

```
public function register(CreateUserRequest $request){
}
```

Now I have other form which need to be validate but the form have addition field.

I know, I can make new Request which contain field in CreateUserRequest + new field.

But I think this is bad way.

So how I can extend the CreateUserRequest and add the other field?

So I can use in other controller method like this

```
public function othermethod(otherCreateUserRequest $request){
}
```

Any help appreciated.

maybe something like this reference [mattstaufer laravel 5.0 form request](https://mattstauffer.co/blog/laravel-5.0-form-requests#separate-form-requests)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can extend your CreateUserRequest class like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use CreateUserRequest;

Class OtherCreateUserRequest extends CreateUserRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return parent::rules() + [
            'additional' => 'rule',
        ];
    }
}
```

Comment: should I create new file named OtherCreateUserRequest? or I can just create new class inside CreateUserRequest file?

Comment: Create a new class in a new file called `OtherCreateUserRequest.php`

Answer (score 0):

I have not tried it but you can inherit the Base Request Class and call it's parent's rule method as:

```
namespace App\Http\Requests;

Class OtherCreateUserRequest extends CreateUserRequest {

    public function rules()
    {
        return array_merge(parent::rules(), [
            'input' => 'more_rules',
        ]);
    }
}
```